# Safely restart nodemon after unhandled exception

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodemon

I'm using gulp and running nodemon from a task. Everytime it detects changes it

- restarts the server
- runs "build" task

Yup in that order. Couldn't figure out how to kick "build" task before nodemon's restart happens (setting `delay` param didn't help).

```
nodemon = require "gulp-nodemon"  
runSequence = require 'run-sequence' # couldn't figure out how to run gulp task
                                     # from another task, so ended up using this

nodemon(
    script:'server.js'
    watch: 'src/**/*.*'
).on "restart" (files)->
    runSequence "build"
```

Now, my problem is - when something happens during build, something that I apparently can't really control (let's say Jade files fail to compile), process throws `uncaughtException` and crashes. What I need though, to restart nodemon, and keep trying building until failing jade file fixed.

I've tried running "build", followed with nodemon in `process.on 'uncaughtException'`, it kinda works, but then nodemon stops watching files and can't recognize changes anymore.

Can you guys advise.

Comment: You can maybe have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971388/prevent-errors-from-breaking-gulp-watch/23973536#23973536