# Prevent errors from breaking / crashing gulp watch

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm running gulp 3.6.2 and have the following task that was set up from a sample online

```
gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function () {
  gulp.watch([
    'views/**/*.html',        
    'public/**/*.js',
    'public/**/*.css'        
  ], function (event) {
    return gulp.src(event.path)
      .pipe(refresh(lrserver));
  });

  gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.coffee'],['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('./app/**/*.scss',['scss']);
});
```

Any time there's an error in my CoffeeScript gulp watch stops - obviously not what I want.

[As recommended elsewhere I tried this](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/71)

```
gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.coffee'],['scripts']).on('error', swallowError);
gulp.watch('./app/**/*.scss',['scss']).on('error', swallowError);
function swallowError (error) { error.end(); }
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

In response to @Aperçu's answer I modified my `swallowError` method and tried the following instead:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/script/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
    .on('error', swallowError);
});
```

Restarted, and then created a syntax error in my coffee file. Same issue:

```
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' after 306 μs

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: W:\bariokart\app\script\trishell.coffee:5:1: error: unexpected *
*
^
  at Stream.modifyFile (W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp-coffee\index.js:37:33)
  at Stream.stream.write (W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp-coffee\node_modules\event-stream\node_modules\through\index.js:26:11)
  at Stream.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
  at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at queueData (W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:43:21)
  at next (W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:71:7)
  at W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:85:7
  at W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\bufferFile.js:8:5
  at fs.js:266:14
  at W:\bariokart\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:104:5
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: see the official gulp recipes at
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes
which have a recipe for ...
combining-streams-to-handle-errors
using stream-combiner2
this is the official answer!

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Your `swallowError` function should look like this:

```
function swallowError (error) {

  // If you want details of the error in the console
  console.log(error.toString())

  this.emit('end')
}
```

I think you have to bind this function on the `error` event of the task that was falling, not the `watch` task, because that's not where comes the problem, you should set this error callback on each task that may fail, like plugins that breaks when you have missed a `;` or something else, to prevent `watch` task to stop.

Examples :

```
gulp.task('all', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/script/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }))
    .on('error', swallowError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))

  gulp.src('css/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ compass: true }))
    .on('error', swallowError)
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

Alternately, if you don't mind to include another module, you can use the **log** function of **[gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util)** to keep you from declare an extra function in your `gulpfile`:

```
.on('error', gutil.log)
```

---

But I may recommend having a look at the awesome **[gulp-plumber](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber)** plugin, which is used to remove the `onerror` handler of the `error` event, causing the break of the streams. It's very simple to use and it stops you from catch all the tasks that may fail.

```
gulp.src('./app/script/*.coffee')
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
```

More info about this on [this article](https://gist.github.com/floatdrop/8269868) by the creator of the concerned plugin.

Comment: I appreciate your help. See my edit. I think I'm doing what you're saying and it still doesn't work

Comment: That's not the `dest` task which is failling, but the `coffee` one, move your error handler one line up.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to reflect the final correct thing to do so anyone that finds this in the future doesn't have to read the comment chain.

Comment: Sure, just done that and adding one of my personal issues in bonus :)

Comment: Please fix .on('error', shallowError) to .on('error', swallowError)

Comment: This is all well and good, but why would I have to write my own error handlers? The whole reason I use gulp or grunt or whatever preprocessing tool, is that it does the dirty work for me. A syntax error somewhere in my code (which is bound to happen) shouldn't grind the whole system to a halt. Compare this to the GUI of Prepros (another preprocessor) - this tool tells you exactly where your error is, and doesn't hang or quit when something is wrong.

Comment: This behavior will be resolved in the 4.0 version. Still, using plumber, you don't have to write any error handler.

Comment: If you want a console beep use: console.log("\x07");

Comment: @Kokodoko And by the way, you can't really compare a closed-source paid software (~30$) that uses a wrapper of `fs.watch` to gulp. Yes you maybe have to add one plugin until v4, but it's free, uses streams, and supported by the community.

Comment: I guess I'm just surprised that such a popular tool still requires so much tweaking to get it to work. 
I don't have anything against a user-friendly GUI though! Many devs seem to be repelled by that idea in itself, open-source or not.

Comment: amazing that no-one throughout has even mentioned steam-combiner2 even though it is the official gulp recipe! plumber also good though but i always prefer to follow gulp recipes, the gulp recipes are kept up to date by gulp and can be viewed at https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes

Comment: @danday74 Good to know! Thus it's not really a friendly solution, I was about to add it to my answer but since you've posted your own I'll let this to you ;)

Comment: `gutil.log` doesn't seem to swallow errors, you still have to use `this.emit('end')` with it.

Comment: @iosdude It worked at some point, curious to know what they changed. Anyway if you want a one-liner, plumber should do the trick :)

Comment: Make sure to `.pipe(plumber())` **before** you pipe int anything else that might error (in this example, `.pipe(coffee(...))`

Comment: Facing the same conundrum, I decided on using a wrapper around `gulp.watch()` that adds an `.on('error', function() { this.emit('end') })` to the result of the watch function, as it's specifically the watch task that I want to make resilient to hanging up. Works really well, and the individual tasks that fail still print their own error messages. See the code: https://github.com/specious/specious.github.io/commit/f8571d28

Answer (score 20):

The above examples didn't work for me. The following did though:

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var liveReload = require('gulp-livereload');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    //only process main.scss which imports all other required styles - including vendor files.
    return gulp.src('./assets/scss/main.scss')
            .pipe(plumber(function (error) {
                gutil.log(error.message);
                this.emit('end');
            }))
            .pipe(compass({
                config_file: './config.rb',
                css: './css'
                , sass: './assets/scss'
            }))
            //minify files
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
            .pipe(minifycss())

            //output
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
            .pipe(notify({message: 'Styles task complete'}));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    liveReload.listen();
    gulp.watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

Comment: This is great, but would also be good to notify if there was an error (currently this just logs error in terminal)

Answer (score 4):

## With one format of files

**(ex: *.coffee only)**

If you want to work only with one format of files, then `gulp-plumber` is your solution.

For example rich handled errors and warning for coffeescripting:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['assets/scripts/**/*.coffee'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(coffeelint())
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(lintThreshold(10, 0, lintThresholdHandler))
    .pipe(coffee({
      bare: true
    }))
    .on('error', swallowError)
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

## With multiple types of file formats

**(ex: *.coffee and *.js at same time)**

But if you won't to work with multiple types of file formats (for example: `*.js` and `*.coffee`), than i will post my solution.

I will just post a self explanatory code over here, with some description before.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  // plumber don't fetch errors inside gulpif(.., coffee(...)) while in watch process
  return gulp.src(['assets/scripts/**/*.js', 'assets/scripts/**/*.coffee'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(gulpif(/[.]coffee$/, coffeelint()))
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(lintThreshold(10, 0, lintThresholdHandler))
    .pipe(gulpif(/[.]coffee$/, coffee({ // if some error occurs on this step, plumber won't catch it
      bare: true
    })))
    .on('error', swallowError)
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

I faced the issue with `gulp-plumber` and `gulp-if` using `gulp.watch(...`

See related issue here: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber/issues/23

So the best option for me was:

- **Each part as file, and concatenate after**. Create multiple tasks that can process each part in separate file (like grunt does), and concatenate them
- **Each part as stream, and merge streams after**. Merge two streams using `merge-stream` (that was made from `event-stream`) into one and continue the job (i tried that first, and it work fine for me, so it is faster solution than previous one)

---

### Each part as stream, and merge streams after

Her is the main part of my code:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  coffeed = gulp.src(['assets/scripts/**/*.coffee'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(coffeelint())
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(lintThreshold(10, 0, lintThresholdHandler))
    .pipe(coffee({
      bare: true
    }))
    .on('error', swallowError);

  jsfiles = gulp.src(['assets/scripts/**/*.js']);

  return merge([jsfiles, coffeed])
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

---

### Each part as file, and concatenate after

If to separate this into parts, then in each part there should be a result file created. For ex.:

```
gulp.task('scripts-coffee', function() {

  return gulp.src(['assets/scripts/**/*.coffee'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(coffeelint())
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(lintThreshold(10, 0, lintThresholdHandler))
    .pipe(coffee({
      bare: true
    }))
    .on('error', swallowError)
    .pipe(concat('application-coffee.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));

});

gulp.task('scripts-js', function() {

  return gulp.src(['assets/scripts/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('application-coffee.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));

});

gulp.task('scripts', ['scripts-js', 'scripts-coffee'], function() {

  var re = gulp.src([
    'dist/scripts/application-js.js', 'dist/scripts/application-coffee.js'
  ])
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));

  del(['dist/scripts/application-js.js', 'dist/scripts/application-coffee.js']);

  return re;

});
```

#### P.S.:

Here node modules and functions that were used:

```
// Load plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    merge = require('ordered-merge-stream'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace'),
    del = require('del'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    gulputil = require('gulp-util'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
    coffeelint = require('gulp-coffeelint),
    lintThreshold = require('gulp-coffeelint-threshold');

var lintThresholdHandler = function(numberOfWarnings, numberOfErrors) {
  var msg;
  gulputil.beep();
  msg = 'CoffeeLint failure; see above. Warning count: ';
  msg += numberOfWarnings;
  msg += '. Error count: ' + numberOfErrors + '.';
  gulputil.log(msg);
};
var swallowError = function(err) {
  gulputil.log(err.toString());
  this.emit('end');
};
```

Comment: I still see improvements for this comments. Like speed comparison, and link for .js files only (excluding minified or 3d party libraries, or libs from bower_components). But basically its easy to adjust and solve this sniffing by Google.com

Answer (score 4):

I like to use gulp plumber because it can add a global listener to a task and have a meaningful message displayed.

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('compile-scss', function () {
    gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Reference : https://scotch.io/tutorials/prevent-errors-from-crashing-gulp-watch

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the following hack as a workaround for https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/71:

```
// Workaround for https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/71
var origSrc = gulp.src;
gulp.src = function () {
    return fixPipe(origSrc.apply(this, arguments));
};
function fixPipe(stream) {
    var origPipe = stream.pipe;
    stream.pipe = function (dest) {
        arguments[0] = dest.on('error', function (error) {
            var state = dest._readableState,
                pipesCount = state.pipesCount,
                pipes = state.pipes;
            if (pipesCount === 1) {
                pipes.emit('error', error);
            } else if (pipesCount > 1) {
                pipes.forEach(function (pipe) {
                    pipe.emit('error', error);
                });
            } else if (dest.listeners('error').length === 1) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
        return fixPipe(origPipe.apply(this, arguments));
    };
    return stream;
}
```

Add it to your gulpfile.js and use it like that:

```
gulp.src(src)
    // ...
    .pipe(uglify({compress: {}}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .on('error', function (error) {
        console.error('' + error);
    });
```

This feels like the most natural error handling to me. If there is no error handler at all, it will throw an error. Tested with Node v0.11.13.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this is to put `gulp watch` in an infinite loop within a Bash (or sh) shell.

`while true; do gulp; gulp watch; sleep 1; done`

Keep the output of this command in a visible area on your screen as you edit your JavaScript. When your edits result in an error, Gulp will crash, print its stack trace, wait for a second, and resume watching your source files. You can then correct the syntax error, and Gulp will indicate whether or not the edit was a success by either printing out it's normal output, or crashing (then resuming) again.

This will work in a Linux or Mac terminal. If you are using Windows, use Cygwin or Ubuntu Bash (Windows 10).

Comment: What language is this? Also, is there any benefit to this over the suggested solutions?

Comment: It's written in Bash/sh. It requires less code than the other solutions and is easier to remember and implement.

Comment: Can you edit the fact that its bash and your other thoughts on this into your answer? I don't agree that its easier then plumber, but its a valid (if not cross platform) approach. I voted down initially because it wasn't clear even what language it was in and I cannot change my vote unless you edit the answer.

Comment: So you prefer crashing the stream and restarting the whole process that might takes quite some depending on what you're doing with an infinite loop rather than simply catching the error? Seems a little disturbing to me.

And speaking of less code, it requires you 16 chars to add plumber to your task whereas your solution takes 36 without counting the `gulp watch`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @GeorgeMauer, I made the edits and wrote about the environments/platforms it works in.

Comment: doesn't work with browser refresh, you'll have to manually refresh the browser after an error.  That'll get confusing fast.

Answer (score 1):

**Typescript**

This is what worked for me.  I work with `Typescript` and separated the function (to aovid confusion with `this` keyword) to handle `less`.  This works with `Javascript` as well.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('less', function() {
    // writing a function to avoid confusion of 'this'
    var l = less({});
    l.on('error', function(err) {
        // *****
        // Handle the error as you like
        // *****
        l.emit('end');
    });

    return gulp
        .src('path/to/.less')
        .pipe(l)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/css/output/dir'))
})
```

Now, when you `watch` `.less` files, and an `error` occurs, the `watch` will not stop and new changes will processed as per your `less task`.

**NOTE** : I tried with `l.end();`; however, it did not work.  However, `l.emit('end');` totally works.

Hope this help.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ->

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        return gulp.src('sass/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass({indentedSyntax: true}))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('sass'));
    }, 300);
});



gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('sass/*.sass', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch'])
```

I just added the
    .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
line, but I had to run the 
    gulp
command as root. I'm running node gulp on a php application so I have multiple accounts on one server, which is why I ran into the issue of gulp breaking on syntax errors because I was not running gulp as root... Maybe plumber and some of the other answers here would have worked for me if I ran as root.
Credit to Accio Code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMR7hq4ABOw for the answer. He said that by handling the error it helps you to determine what line the error is on and what it is in the console, but also stops gulp from breaking on syntax error. He said it was kind of a light weight fix, so not sure if it will work for what you are looking for. Quick fix though, worth a shot. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: but now your CI pipeline no longer sees an error.