# Prevent non-stream errors from breaking gulp watch

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have followed the recommended solutions found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971388/prevent-errors-from-breaking-gulp-watch), but I am still seeing errors which break my watchers.

Given a watcher like this:

```
var through = require('through2');
var watch   = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('catchall', function() {
  return watch('gulpfile.js')
    .pipe(through.obj(externalFunc))
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Inside error handler:', err);
    });
});
```

With externalFunc defined as:

```
function externalFunc(file, enc, done) {
  throw new Error("I have been compromised - Abort mission!");
}
```

I would expect to see output of:

```
[10:52:51] Starting 'catchall'...
[10:52:53] gulpfile.js was changed
Inside error handler: I have been compromised - Abort mission!
```

Instead, I get no output from `externalFunc`, and instead get standard error output and a stacktrace:

```
[10:52:51] Starting 'catchall'...
[10:52:53] gulpfile.js was changed

/my/path/to/gulpfile.js:27
  throw new Error("I have been compromised - Abort mission!");
        ^
Error: I have been compromised - Abort mission!
    at DestroyableTransform.externalFunc [as _transform] ....
```

Most importantly, the watcher crashes.

Why does this error not get trapped by the `on('error')` listener, and what can I do in a gulp watcher to handle these errors without exiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not getting trapped into the error listener, because as you said, this is not a stream error.

You're actually throwing an error to your *node process* which runs *gulp*, and not catching it, so it behaves as an `uncaughtException` and completely crash everything, without waiting for the error handler you've set to do its work.

Just for the demo, but not recommended, you can do something like this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (er) {
  console.error('Throwing error:', er);
});
```

The error will be logged and your gulp watch will still run.

I may advice you to have a look to [Node Domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) to handle your errors safety, though I don't know if it's really a bad practice to use `uncaughtException` in something like gulp.